# C# equivalent of (reading a variable as a different type)

Tags: c#, c++, variables, pointers

I have been converting some part of my application from C++ to C#. There's this encoding/decoding part which I need to read a variable as a float which is defined as uint:

```
uint result = 0;

... // a value is set to result

return (*((float *)&result)); // get result as a float value
```

Anyway to convert last line to C#? Thank you all..

Comment: If i have not misunderstood this question, you can do it like `return Convert.ToSingle(result);` in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with unsafe code - or you could use `BitConverter.GetBytes()` to convert the value into a byte array, and then `BitConverter.ToSingle()` to convert back. That's less efficient, obviously, but will work if you're in a situation where you can't use unsafe code.

EDIT: There's another alternative that I've used in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), using a C-like "union" to work much more like your original example, but via a custom struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct Int32SingleUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    int i;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    float f;

    internal Int32SingleUnion(int i)
    {
        this.f = 0; // Just to keep the compiler happy
        this.i = i;
    }

    internal Int32SingleUnion(float f)
    {
        this.i = 0; // Just to keep the compiler happy
        this.f = f;
    }

    internal int AsInt32
    {
        get { return i; }
    }

    internal float AsSingle
    {
        get { return f; }
    }
}
```

(You could do the same thing for long and double of course.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx). For example,

```
return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(result), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1) Use C# pointers. The compiler will allow you if you enable "unsafe code" in the project's properties. Please read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=VS.100).aspx

2) Use the BitConverter class. Specifically, BitConverter.GetBytes() convert your uint to bytes, and then BitConverter.ToSingle() to convert the bytes to float. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `BitConverter` class is your friend here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx